# How to mantain the RESTful design of my own applications

Tags: rest, cakephp-2.0

As far as I know, the peculiarity of a REST web service is the *resource* concept. Everything should rotate around the resource and its CRUD operations. Suppose that one resource is the *player* resource, I can retrive player's list at the link http://mydomain.com/players.xml, the 5th player is reachable at http://mydomain.com/players/5.xml, and so on, using proper HTTP method, I can perform different CRUD actions.

Now on the client side the issue is: What if I need to show a table with player's score (you can assume that this table is build on the fly, querying the player's DB table). In my hopinion, this table isn't a real resource (I can't delete table, neither I can't edit or add new table).

Then the real question is (considering I'm using CakePHP framework): What can I do to have my player's table without broke the RESTish style of player's controller?

My first idea is: add method `getTable()` to prexistent four CRUD methods (`index()`, `view()`, `edit()` and `delete()`) of players controller, modify the `routes.php` configuration file in a way that all the REST API will reachable under `rest` path (i.e. http://mydomain.com/rest/players/5.xml) while all other service, non RESTFUL, will be reachable under `nonrest` path (i.e. http://mydomain.com/nonrest/players/getTable or http://mydomain.com/nonrest/players/getTable.xml). In this way the API's client will surely know that under the `rest` path the REST paradigm is respected.
Is a good solution? Have you any other idea?

Comment: REST is about resources, and representations, and discoverability. It should — in principle — be possible for a general browser to go to a resource and figure out how to use it with just information that the resource provides. Practice isn't so convenient, alas, since most resources don't serve up semantic descriptions of their underlying model (and no, a JS app for working with the resource isn't a substitute!)

Comment: Please don't put `rest` and `nonrest` in your URLs! What you describe is a resource. Just because it doesn't accept PUT, PATCH and DELETE doesn't make it less of a resource. @fumanchu's answer is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a separate `nonrest` hierarchy; there's absolutely nothing wrong with `http://mydomain.com/players/5/score.xml`. Just because a resource is read-only does not thereby make it something other than a resource.